# Can't get stack trace of an exception while executing Instrumented tests using Android Test Orchestrator

Tags: java, android, testing, jenkins

I have a test suite that runs multiple instrumentation tests using Android Test Orchestrator in order to ensure that all of them were executed. Other way if one of tests crashes - other tests won't get executed. With Android Test Orchestrator each test runs in it's own instance of an app and following tests are not affected by previous ones.

And everything is great, until a test crashes and I want to see an error message, but it just says - `Test instrumentation process crashed.  Check com.sample.application.ApplianceInfoTest#applianceDetailsTest.txt for details`

this txt file is saved on the device itself. All the tests are continuously  executed on Jenkins pipeline and the HTML report on tests generated in `build\reports\androidTests\connected` folder of a project is used to display statistics on pipeline and it there is the same message `Test instrumentation process crashed.  Check com.sample.application.ApplianceInfoTest#applianceDetailsTest.txt for details`

Question - How do I get stack trace of an error?

Comment: do you want to see the stacktrace on the jenkins console?

Comment: there as well, in the end - output from the tests should be saved in junit report

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any way to get the underlying stack trace.

It is currently impossible (though please post a link if you find it!) to even review the code to verify my assertion there is no flag that would allow viewing of the stack trace

If you follow the documentation links here, you will eventually get a 404 on github, and the code isn't visible https://opensource.google.com/projects/android-testing-support-library